# CoreData: Storing custom classes as JSON or individual values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm new to CoreData and working on a swift project. I'm currently saving custom classes as NSManagedObjects that depend on each other and persist.  However some of the fields I'm storing are arrays of custom classes.  For example, a game I am storing has a name and multiple "Dice" which are custom classes.  Would I store the dice as a transformable value in CoreData or is it easier to store the all the individual game key/values as a JSON string in a single field instead?

What's best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: You really need to show your existing model, a sample of the data and explain what it's used for and how. It sounds like you're comparing binary or string formatted data storage anyway rather than entities - do you need to search the data store based on this content?

Comment: you dice class should also be a `NSManagedObject` and then both should be linked together with a relation.